# Binary Search Tree using the most frequent node to print out certain statements

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, frequency

I have a binary search tree that I want to use to be able to give a certain output for the most common node but i'm having a hard time doing that. I already have code that prints out how many times the node is entered into the tree and which one is the most frequent but I don't know how to write the if statement that would compare the values and be able to output certain things if one was greater than the other. I have been working on this for hours and just can't get the right output please help. 
So if i have more a's i want that to have a certain output or if i have more b's that should have a different output etc.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? There is a lot of code and that makes it hard to read the question. To make sure the question is as clear as possible, thus getting best answers, only include the relevant parts of the code, leaving out everything unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, change the `node` definition to look more like the one below. This definition initializes all the struct's fields to their zero values. For me, this change prevented an access violation at the line `if (p->data == q->data)`, probably because the `next` pointer was not initialized to `nullptr`.

```
struct node {
    char data{};
    int count{};
    node *left{};
    node *right{};
    int height{};
    node *next{};
};
```

Similarly, my compiler warns about an uninitialized variable `res`. So that too should be initialized like `char res{};`.

This seems to work for the `maxChar` function. The second overload calls the first overload, which calls itself recursively. They don't have to have the same names.

```
char maxChar(node *node, int max, char res) {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        res = maxChar(node->left, max, res);
        if (node->count > max) {
            max = node->count;
            res = node->data;
        }
        res = maxChar(node->right, max, res);
    }
    return res;
}

char maxChar(node *node) {
    int max{};
    char res{};
    return maxChar(node, max, res);
}
```

Then if needed, you could do something like this:

```
    char maxCh = maxChar(root);
    switch (maxCh) {
    case 'A': cout << "Your recommendation is A." << endl;
        break;
    case 'B': cout << "Your recommendation is B." << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Okay I removed some code and I changed the node.h. But how do you compare what ever data is the max to certain value? For example if a was inserted twice and b was inserted once and c was inserted 4 times. How do i write a if statement to say some like if(max = 'A') cout<<"Your answer is.."<<endl; and so on for all the other values. That's what i'm stuck on i've tried many different things and just can't get it right.

Comment: @userstudent I updated this answer with my own version of the `maxChar` function. If I understand what you need, that should do it.

Comment: @userstudent I added a `switch` example, in case that helps you. Depending on what you need to print for each case, it may or may not be useful.

Comment: Of course a switch statement I don't know how I didn't think about that that's exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you so much.